# calling the api route from another c# project

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a controller with the route 
For example:

```
[Route("api/insertDetails")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateModel]
public IHttpActionResult InsertUserDetails([FromBody]UserModel userDetails)
```

the full uri: `http://localhost:5484/api/insertDetails`

Now i have another project from where i have to send user details..
How can I do this using that uri?
I have run the web api project, but what's next?

Comment: Reference the other project in the Web API project, create an object of appropriate class and call method on that object... that's how you do it..

Comment: You need to make a post http request via HttpClient with required payload